# Issue with table side-by-side only on Outlook software

Tags: email, outlook

I'm creating a HTML email, it works fine on all the mail clients I tested except on Outlook 2016 software (works fine on Outlook website)

I tried to use td side-by-side instead of table but it's breaking my responsiveness. Tables are supposed to side-by-side splitting the email in 2 parts. In Outlook software, there is a big gap above the second table making if shifted and not aligned with the first one.

Here is my code:

```
  <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
      <table align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="ee_element ee_textelement" data-title="Text" style="width: 700px; table-layout: auto;" width="700">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
              <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="em_wrapper" style="width:700px;table-layout: auto;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="em_wrapper" style="width:350px;table-layout: auto;" width="350">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" class="em_pad_top" valign="top">
                              <table align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sbs_block h_auto" style="width: 350px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);table-layout: auto;height:400px" width="350">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#00865B" class="col" style="vertical-align: middle;" width="350">
                                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>
                                            <p style="color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0;font-size:16px">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="em_wrapper" style="width:350px;table-layout: auto;" width="350">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" class="em_pad_top" valign="top">
                              <table align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sbs_block h_auto" style="width: 350px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);table-layout: auto;height:400px" width="350">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#00865B" class="col" style="vertical-align: middle;" width="350">
                                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>
                                            <p style="color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0;font-size:16px">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </table>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm expecting to have my 2 tables properly aligned side-by-side like I have them on all other email clients.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO!

To do this - you will need to place the following snippet between your 2 left aligned tables:

```
<!--[if mso]>
   </td>
   <td valign="top" align="center">
<![endif]-->
```

Due to the nature of MSO - it doesn't support table floating, so this effectively lies to MSO and turns them into 2 columns.

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
  <table align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="ee_element ee_textelement" data-title="Text" style="width: 700px; table-layout: auto;" width="700">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="em_wrapper" style="width:700px;table-layout: auto;" width="100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="em_wrapper" style="width:350px;table-layout: auto;" width="350">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="em_pad_top" valign="top">
                          <table align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sbs_block h_auto" style="width: 350px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);table-layout: auto;height:400px" width="350">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#00865B" class="col" style="vertical-align: middle;" width="350">
                                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>
                                        <p style="color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0;font-size:16px">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <!--[if mso]>
                     </td>
                     <td valign="top" align="center">
                  <![endif]-->
                  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="em_wrapper" style="width:350px;table-layout: auto;" width="350">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="em_pad_top" valign="top">
                          <table align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sbs_block h_auto" style="width: 350px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);table-layout: auto;height:400px" width="350">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#00865B" class="col" style="vertical-align: middle;" width="350">
                                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>
                                        <p style="color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0;font-size:16px">Lorem Ipsum</p>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
```

Just one of the many quirks with mso :)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. Unfortunately, tables are now one under the other. Any idea?